# Saving Offline data into CB Lite 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase-lite

issue : ( CB Lite 2.0 , Swift)

Registration screen which has name, email and dob and want to save in couchbase lite.
everytime user-filled form with these fields I want to store in local CB Lite DB
After that i want to fetch all record store in the cb lite.
Issue is :

Created a document

stored name , emal and dob in swift dictionary and tried to save and it stores but everytime i fetch it shows only one , not other user information.

Kinldy help me on this.

Raised Query on Couchbase Forum :

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/saving-offline-data-into-cb-lite-2-0/17877?u=st.shubh.tiwari

Comment: The question is a little unclear.  Are you saying you're storing more than one set of user information, but only able to retrieve one?  Are you saving different user information in different docs with unique IDs?

Comment: @Hod i was just trying to save push notification to cblite 2.0 and try to fetch it , there is no sync feature only i want to save and fetch , so when i was saving then try to fetch it was giving me only one record so i tried another way as i mention in my answer and it works , could you check is it right way or you could provide me input on it ,i will try it . Thanks

Comment: Other than a couple places where it looks like the code might be tightened up, I don't see any problem with your solution.

Comment: @Hod i got stuck one issue , replicator not stopping , even i posted on couchbase community , could you suggest something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way i called by taking one sample notification and checked its working :

```
let dict = [
                    "alert": "push notification.. (5)",
                    "badge": 1,
                    "sound": "default"
                ] as [String : Any]

            var notificationArray = [Dictionary<String,Any>]()

            let notiDict = CouchDBHelper.fetchDocumentByDocId(documentID: Constants.notificationDocument)

            if let notiArray = notiDict["notification"] as? [Dictionary<String,Any>] {
                notificationArray = notiArray
            }
            notificationArray.append(dict)

            CCouchDBHelper.insertNotificationData(data: notificationArray, doc_id: Constants.notificationDocument)
            objNotifcationSource = notificationArray
            objNotificationTable.reloadData()



       public func insertNotificationData(data:Any?,doc_id:String)
        {
            //let sharedInstance = CouchbaseAdapter.sharedInstance
            let doc = MutableDocument(id: doc_id) 

            doc.setValue(data, forKey: "notification")

            do {
                try database.saveDocument(doc)
                //try sharedInstance.database.saveDocument(doc)
                print("Inserted Record :", data as! NSArray)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error in saving",error)
            }

            fetchDocumentByDocId(documentID: doc_id)
        }
```